# EC2 volumes & partitioning

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

With Amazon EC2 CentOS 7 HVM community image machine just thinking for volumes & partitioning. Would it not be good that I create default 8GB volume sda for root device for all operating system and other related updates and for all my website data create another volume sdb (size according to my need)?

Also since I would be saving my website date to /var/www on volume sbd, but as /var is already created on volume /sda would it be better to create new directory on as /www (instead of /var/www) and mount it or both approcahes are fine. I have seen incidents where /var/www fails with fstab entry during boot while /www mounts fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my suggestion:

- `/dev/sda` [root disk] filesystem mounted at `/`
- `/dev/sdb` [data disk] filesystem mounted at `/var/www` or `/www`
- `/dev/sdc` [log disk] filesystem mounted at `/var/log`

Separating your application data to another disk is a good decision. If for some reason, e.g. faulty distro upgrade, your root disk becomes unbootable you could still be able to take your data disk to another machine. The exact mount point is not that important, it is better that you choose one path that makes sense with the application you'll deploy, so `/var/www` is fine.

There's actually no difference between `/var/www` and `/www` to mount your second disk because both `/var` and `/www` will lie on the same filesystem on top of disk `sda`. Since this filesystem happens to be the root one, ie where the OS is installed, if an error happens your server will most likely not boot up and your second disk will not be able to be mounted on either `/var` or `/www`. So I suggest you choose the one that makes more sense to your application.

You will notice that I have added a third recommendation and this comes from our experience. Many applications log by default under `/var/log` and keeping it on the root disk has proven a limitation since we need to be constantly freeing up space, even with a decent logrotate configuration. By mounting `/var/log` onto another disk we could keep the root filesystem within a reasonable size range.

Comment: So, let's say if I am going to mount `/var/log` to `/dev/sdc` than what about the old data(if any) which was already there as when the OS was initiated under `/var/log`.

Comment: Old data (if any) will remain on your root disk `/dev/sda` but it will no longer be accessible at `/var/log`. If you wish to see the old data you can use a bind mount. A simple example would be: `mkdir /bindmnt && mount --bind / /bindmnt`, old data will be now accessible at `/bindmnt/var/log`. More information about bind mount points can be found [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount)

Comment: That's fine that I can access the old data, but my question is different.... like if I am going to mount `/var/log` to any drive how will my OS will bootup? as `/var/log` already contains many OS related logs directories and files which it created during installation
**anaconda
audit
boot.log
and many others...**

Comment: I see. Linux applications usually follow a convention on where to store different types of files, see [here](http://linux.die.net/man/7/hier). `/var/log` is usually to store logfiles which are not mandatory to exist for an application to run, if the files/directories do not exist, the application will create them at runtime. So your server will boot up normally and the applications will recreate the files/directories in `/var/log` that they need. I cannot be sure if all your applications follow these convention so I suggest that you test it first on a non-production server.

Comment: Ok, Just out of curiosity what happens by default when we mount any drive to a directory which already contains important system files... like what if I am going to mount a drive to `/dev` or `/boot`

Comment: For `/dev` you most probably break the system since some hardware will no longer be recognised. Nevertheless, any files open prior the mount will remain open even if the file is not visible on the filesystem structure. That means that most probably your terminal session will still be accessible after mountin a new `/dev` filesystem (_note that I have never tried_). The `/boot` mountpoint will not be a problem for a running server since it is only used when the server boots. Even then, since the kernel is only presented with the root disk, only the old `/boot` files will be used.

Comment: If you mount a new filesystem on top of `/usr` or `/proc` you will screw up your server